# How to make Back Color transparent ON

Tags: vb.net

I've got a weird problem: I've tried to make a transparent color in vb.net but I cannot using following code:

```
Me.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent
```

But any other color is working fine, for example:

```
Me.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime
```

but when trying set it in properties to transparent, I get the following error from debugger: http://prntscr.com/f54sbb

Any help guys?

Comment: Whatever `Me` is, the BackColor of it cannot be set to Transparent.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Bring the error into the question as text rather than an image offsite.

Comment: i found a solution here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor(v=vs.110).aspx
but dunno how perform it exactly. someone can guide me?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a Form then you can make it transparent by setting a TransparencyKey and then setting the BackColor to that color.

```
 Me.TransparencyKey = Color.Magenta
 Me.BackColor = Color.Magenta
```